# Angular 11 catch direct requests to backend API

Tags: angular, .net-core, routes, controller

I create a site based on angular 11 with .net core.

In my solution I created some controller, and want to call it not from angular component or service, but directly, from browser or different service.
And in that case, angular catch request, looks for relevant component on it's routes and shows "page not found" error.

How can I configure angular, .net core or IIS to allow direct requests to controllers?
Thanks.

My Controller:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PubSubController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Notify")]
        public IActionResult Notify()
        {
            return Ok("OK");
        }
    }
```

The Url I call:
`http://angularApp/api/PubSub/Notify`.

Answer (score 0):

They way you presented the URL (http://angularApp/api/PubSub/Notify) and assuming that you want to bypass the angular routing and hit the "controller" from the API is not possible. Based on your URL, you are using PathLocationStrategy and it takes advantage of a relatively new HTML5 API called pushstate (from the HTML5 history API). So all the URLs will be interpreted by the Angular router service. In order to get this functionality, I would shift the Angular to HashLocationStrategy and in this way the entire SPA site would be relative to a base URL and you can use the other URLs to hit the "controllers" from the API.
In the **Startup.cs** in **Configure** method you can do something like this:

```
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var url = context.Request.Path.Value;
            
            if (url.Contains("/api/PubSub/Notify"))
            {
                // ...do your things
                //....context.Response.Redirect(urlRedirect, permanent: false);
                return;   // short circuit
            }

            await next();
        });
```

to avoid to return the response to your SPA default URL.